# docker import giving invalid handle error

Tags: docker

I have a .tar file and a .tar.gz file of Cassandra. I want to create my own image from it. I am on Windows10 and thought I can use `docker import` but I keep getting error.

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu>docker import apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz - manucassandra:0:0:1
invalid reference format

C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu>docker import apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz -manucassandra:0:0:1
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(duplicates of file paths not supported):

C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu>docker import apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar -manucassandra:0:0:1
error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/images/create?fromSrc=-&message=anucassandra%3A0%3A0%3A1&repo=&tag=: read apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar: The handle is invalid.
```

How can I make my own image from Cassandra distribution?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the Official image? They have the version that your are trying to import.  `docker pull cassandra:<<version>>`

Comment: just want to learn how things work. So am trying to do things from scratch